# How to group a few row values together to put into a new table?

Tags: group-by, query, database-agnostic

I have a table:

```
+-----------+-------+
|   risk    | count |
+-----------+-------+
| high      |     5 |
| low       |    30 |
| medium    |    81 |
| very high |     2 |
| very low  |    72 |
+-----------+-------+
```

I want to group certain values (low, very low) together into a new row named "Other". How should I do this ?

I know I need to create a new table based on select statement and I looked into group by but that only groups like names together. Is this even possible?

I want the result table to be like this:

```
+-----------+-------+
|   risk    | count |
+-----------+-------+
| high      |     5 |
| medium    |    81 |
| very high |     2 |
| Other     |   102 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: Please be aware that basic SQL questions are [off-topic here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but on-topic for [SO].

Answer (score 2):

I think the following query should produce the required result:

```
SELECT 
    DECODE(RISK,'very low','other','low','other',RISK) RISK,
    SUM(COUNT) COUNT 
FROM TEST_RESULT 
GROUP BY 
    DECODE(RISK,'very low','other','low','other',RISK);
```

You have not mentioned a table name, I have used `TEST_RESULT`.

Following is my complete worksheet:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_RESULT (RISK VARCHAR2(20),COUNT NUMBER(5));

INSERT INTO TEST_RESULT VALUES ('high',5);
INSERT INTO TEST_RESULT VALUES ('low',30);
INSERT INTO TEST_RESULT VALUES ('medium',81);
INSERT INTO TEST_RESULT VALUES ('very high',2);
INSERT INTO TEST_RESULT VALUES ('very low',72);


SELECT 
    DECODE(RISK,'very low','other','low','other',RISK) RISK,
    SUM(COUNT) COUNT 
FROM TEST_RESULT 
GROUP BY 
    DECODE(RISK,'very low','other','low','other',RISK);
```

The question does not mention a database product, but it seemed to me like a standard SQL problem. I had Oracle DB available, so I used Oracle.

Comment: If your variant of SQL doesn't have the `DECODE` function, you can use `CASE`: `CASE risk WHEN 'low' THEN 'Other' WHEN 'Very low' THEN 'Other' ELSE risk END` should be equivalent to the `DECODE` statement, and more generically available.